# Fill null-values in-place by column type: TypeError: ("'NoneType' object is not callable", 'occurred at index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to build a function that can select numerical or object dtypes and replace NaN values with a value relevant to the dtype i.e. 0 for numerical and 'Missing Value' for object.

My code and errors are:

`test_df.select_dtypes(include=[float,int]).apply(test_df.fillna(0, inplace=True))`

> TypeError: ("'NoneType' object is not callable", 'occurred at index Word Count')

`test_df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).apply(test_df.fillna('Missing Value', inplace=True))`

> TypeError: ("'NoneType' object is not callable", 'occurred at index Address')

I'm not sure how to solve these errors. Also if someone thinks I'm going about it the wrong way happy to see another solution. I need to preform this action a lot and looking for the most efficient way to get the job done.

I've read though some similar posts but the issues seem to be very specific to the persons particular problem and code.

Any help is appreciated.

Example Data:

```
data = {'Address': {0: 'https://www.example.com/',
  1: 'https://www.example.com/predictions/doncaster-rovers-vs-shrewsbury-predictions-betting-tips-match-previews/',
  3: 'https://www.example.com/freetips/free-golf-betting-tips/',
  4: 'https://www.example.com/news/',
  6: 'https://www.example.com/leagues/sky-bet-championship/',
  7: 'https://www.example.com/freetips/f1-betting-tips-predictions/',
  8: 'https://www.example.com/bankroll-builder/',
  11: 'https://www.example.com/predictions/hartlepool-vs-eastleigh-predictions-betting-tips-match-previews/',
  12: 'https://www.example.com/over-2-5-goals-betting-tips-and-predictions/',
  13: 'https://www.example.com/terms-conditions/',
  14: 'https://www.example.com/tips/nhl-2019-2020-season-picks-betting-tips/',
  15: 'https://www.example.com/news/9-1-win-accumulator-lands-on-monday-night/',
  16: 'https://www.example.com/leagues/sky-bet-league-1/',
  18: 'https://www.example.com/daily-double-tips/',
  19: 'https://www.example.com/leagues/europa-league/',
  21: 'https://www.example.com/freetips/free-snooker-betting-tips/',
  23: 'https://www.example.com/leagues/uefa-champions-league/',
  24: 'https://www.example.com/daily-treble-tips/',
  25: 'https://www.example.com/freetips/free-darts-betting-tips/',
  26: 'https://www.example.com/app/'},
 'Content': {0: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  1: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  3: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  4: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  6: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  7: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  8: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  11: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  12: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  13: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  14: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  15: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  16: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  18: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  19: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  21: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  23: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  24: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  25: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  26: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'},
 'Title 1': {0: 'Free Sports Betting Tips From Professional Betting Tipsters',
  1: 'Doncaster Rovers vs Shrewsbury Predictions & Tips',
  3: 'Free Golf Betting Tips, Predictions & Golf Betting Odds',
  4: 'Football Betting Blog | Free Super Tips',
  6: 'Championship Predictions & Championship Betting Tips',
  7: 'F1 Racing Betting Tips and Predictions | Free Super Tips',
  8: 'Betting Bankroll Builder | Free Football Betting Tips | Free Super Tips',
  11: 'Hartlepool vs Eastleigh Predictions & Tips',
  12: 'Over 2.5 Goals Tips & Over 1.5 Goals Betting Predictions',
  13: 'Terms & Conditions | Free Super Tips',
  14: 'NHL 2019-2020 Season Picks & Betting Tips',
  15: '9/1 Win Accumulator lands on Monday night!',
  16: 'League One Predictions & League One Betting Tips | Football Betting',
  18: 'Daily Double Tips | Free Super Tips',
  19: 'Europa League Predictions & Europa League Betting Tips',
  21: 0,
  23: 'Champions League Predictions & Champions League Betting Tips',
  24: 'Daily Treble Tips | Free Football Betting Tips | Free Super Tips',
  25: 'Free Darts Betting Tips and Predictions | Free Super Tips',
  26: 'FreeSuperTips Mobile App for iPhone and Android | Download Now!'},
 'H1-1': {0: 'The Home of Free Sports Betting Tips',
  1: 'Doncaster vs Shrewsbury Predictions',
  3: 'Latest Golf Betting Tips',
  4: 'News Articles',
  6: 'Championship Predictions & Championship Betting Tips',
  7: 'Latest F1 Betting Tips & Predictions',
  8: 'Bankroll Builder',
  11: 'Hartlepool vs Eastleigh Predictions',
  12: 'Over 2.5 Goals Betting Tips and Predictions',
  13: 'Terms & Conditions',
  14: 'NHL 2019-2020 Season Picks & Betting Tips',
  15: '9/1 Win Accumulator lands on Monday night!',
  16: 'League One Predictions & League One Betting Tips',
  18: 'Daily Double Tips',
  19: 'Europa League Predictions & Europa League Betting Tips',
  21: 0,
  23: 'Champions League Predictions & Champions League Betting Tips',
  24: 'Daily Treble',
  25: 'Latest Darts Tips',
  26: 'Download The App'},
 'H1-2': {0: 'The Home of Free Sports Betting Tips',
  1: 0,
  3: 'Free Golf Betting Tips',
  4: 0,
  6: 0,
  7: 'Free F1 Betting Tips',
  8: 'Bankroll Builder',
  11: 0,
  12: 'Free Over 2.5 Goals Tips',
  13: 0,
  14: 0,
  15: 0,
  16: 0,
  18: 'What is a Daily Double?',
  19: 0,
  21: 0,
  23: 0,
  24: 'Free Daily Treble Tips',
  25: 'Free Darts Betting Tips',
  26: 0},
 'H2-1': {0: 'Welcome to Free Super Tips',
  1: 'Predictions & Tips',
  3: 'Free Golf Betting Tips',
  4: 'Sign Up To Our Email Newsletter',
  6: 'Sky Bet Championship Predictions 2019/20',
  7: 'F1 Betting Tips & Predictions',
  8: 'Bankroll',
  11: 'Predictions & Tips',
  12: 'How does goal betting work?',
  13: 0,
  14: 'Boston Bruins to Win the Stanley Cup',
  15: 'Sign Up To Our Email Newsletter',
  16: 'League 1 Betting Previews',
  18: 'Where should I back your daily double tips?',
  19: 'UEFA Europa League Predictions 2019/20',
  21: 0,
  23: 'UEFA Champions League Predictions 2019/20',
  24: 'What is a Daily Treble?',
  25: 'Free Darts Betting Tips & Predictions',
  26: 0},
 'H2-2': {0: 'Today’s Free Football Betting Tips',
  1: 'Reason For Doncaster vs Shrewsbury Predictions',
  3: 'When Are Your Golf Tips Posted?',
  4: 0,
  6: 'Championship Betting Previews',
  7: 'This Weeks Formula 1 Betting Tips',
  8: 'Bets',
  11: 'Reason For Hartlepool vs Eastleigh Predictions',
  12: 'What are the advantages of betting on Over 2.5 Goals tips?',
  13: 0,
  14: 'Dallas Stars to Win the Stanley Cup',
  15: 0,
  16: 'When do you post your League 1 Tips?',
  18: 'Where can I get a free bet to back your\xa0daily double?',
  19: 'Europa League Final Predictions',
  21: 0,
  23: 'Champions League Final Predictions',
  24: 'What are the advantages of a Daily Treble?',
  25: 'When Are Your Darts Tips Posted?',
  26: 0},
 'Word Count': {0: 2194,
  1: 2052,
  3: 1169,
  4: 1520,
  6: 1311,
  7: 973,
  8: 698,
  11: 2019,
  12: 1540,
  13: 972,
  14: 1486,
  15: 1720,
  16: 1123,
  18: 684,
  19: 1677,
  21: 0,
  23: 1699,
  24: 818,
  25: 1520,
  26: 328},
 'Text Ratio': {0: 11.52079,
  1: 8.852077,
  3: 9.677187,
  4: 10.943003,
  6: 10.753424,
  7: 8.455938,
  8: 5.3081274,
  11: 9.528880000000001,
  12: 11.084525,
  13: 10.7027025,
  14: 10.938739,
  15: 12.078298,
  16: 8.26281,
  18: 5.3075795,
  19: 12.4630165,
  21: 0.0,
  23: 14.116589999999999,
  24: 6.197794,
  25: 12.040536999999999,
  26: 3.7226769999999996},
 'Hash': {0: '3ab5ba34a7c581e883016049e28848cb',
  1: 'b255533806a97449e445d66690e6e007',
  3: '9ff9a83314e16aabf989686db460d014',
  4: '8af6446deabe06eada8e6904af182d20',
  6: 'e93988549da9e7bd40c5744cdd42e817',
  7: 'e193daa50f94d2a94b97f4bdd077a468',
  8: '26e4fe9a95e069d5d413e05e24f4af90',
  11: 'd7e1b955b137503cdbe3b59c04a95b73',
  12: 'abff28a712fae7a29c981d20ade64b3d',
  13: 'bf83435ce5015b77dba70e103402f927',
  14: '8964c47ec078178b8648f51bd6b1200f',
  15: 'de9beacf3baa076b0bafcaf8da8f398c',
  16: '56d40290ecfb52421759097f96797fe6',
  18: '27d4a921fa5ac189418ce880beabdf2a',
  19: '995417328e28075ceb2a1e01fc38198d',
  21: 0,
  23: '7914bf5e45a5f2731d9b3ad266b38c19',
  24: '8c180a043597529daeb8948b8f916c89',
  25: '3856cca3e8809531bcf02189fdd1c2d',
  26: 'f2e3259f5a4938deca7b37d88fddd6cd'}}

test_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Comment: `.apply` expects a *callable*, i.e. a *function*, but you are passing it the result of `test_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)`, which is `None`.

Comment: If I wrap the `test_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)` in a custom function it should work?

Comment: It will solve that error, yes.

Comment: cant you just write it as `test_df.select_dtypes(include=[float,int]).fillna(0, inplace=True)` I dont have any pandas experience bu fill na seems to apply to the df

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've tried your solution and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @NickDuddy you **must provide a [mcve]**. Or else this just becomes a game of guess and check. Note, what you are doing *will give you some sort of error*, a different one, because `fillna(0, inplace=True)` returns a data-frame, not `None`, but that is still not a callable

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've provided all the code and the data in form of a dict at the bottom. As I mentioned it's giving me the exact same error.

Comment: @NickDuddy ah, I see, in any case, you need to pass a callable, it can't just be what you have wraped in a function.

Comment: @NickDuddy better yet, you don't need `.apply` at all, i've posted a solution

Answer (score 1):

So, you have to pass a callable to `.apply`, which is causing the error, but you don't need apply. It does nothing for you. You want to modify your data-frame in-place. You can take advantage of the "values=" argument to `fillna`:

```
Parameters
----------
value : scalar, dict, Series, or DataFrame
    Value to use to fill holes (e.g. 0), alternately a
    dict/Series/DataFrame of values specifying which value to use for
    each index (for a Series) or column (for a DataFrame).  Values not
    in the dict/Series/DataFrame will not be filled. This value cannot
    be a list.
```

But you just have to create the dictionary, you can do that using something like:

```
int_or_float_cols = {c:0 for c in  test_df.head(0).select_dtypes(include=[float,int])}
object_cols = {c:"Missing" for c in test_df.head(0).select_dtypes(include=[object])}
test_df.fillna(value={**int_or_float_cols,**object_cols}, inplace=True)
```